# Raspbian : receive files from android through bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to send file from Android device to raspbian, using bluetooth communication.
I actually have the connection between the two devices, but when I try to send a file, it appears that the file is not sent.

[EDITED]

On the raspberry pi3, with raspbian installed, I launch the "bluetoothctl" command line, I go on my Android App, I select a file and a bluetooth device which will receive this file, I clic on "SEND" and the following lines appears on my Raspberry Shell :

```
[CHG] Device aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:D0 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device aa:aa:aa:aa:aa:D0 Connected: no
```

Of course, both devices are paired and trusted before trying to send the file.

I have been searching for couple of days, without any result.

Any idea ?

Comment: We'll need more detail than "I launch the 'bluetoothctl'" and "the following activity start". Show the command line you use. How do you "send the file from the android device"?

Comment: @JimmyB, the command line that I used is "bluetoothctl". This command line allow me to interact with the raspberry pi bluetooth. And that's all for raspberry side. In the other side, I have made an android App with a friend, we are both novice, that allow me to select a file, select a bluetooth device, and send this selected file to the selected device.
When I press "send" in my App, I just look to my raspberry Shell, and I can see "Connected on" and "Connected off".
In my App, the following message is displayed "file xxxx not sent".
I don't know if that is clear ?

Comment: @JimmyB : I edited my post. I agree, it was not clear. I hope it is better now

Comment: There are multiple ways to transfer a file over bluetooth, e.g. via built-in [OBEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange) or via a custom protocol over SPP. Tell/show us how your Android code does the "SEND" part.

Comment: @JimmyB : Late response due to my project that finish soon. I will work on the Bluetooth transfer after the May 18th. Thanks again for helping !